# Core search, use wildcards by default

Tags: 7, search

I've been trying to Google my way out of this one but I can't seem to find a solid solution for using wildcards by default for the core search module. Only things I can find are patches which aren't really looking like totally stable. And I want my customer's multi-lingual production site to be as stable as possible.

So, the current situation is as follows:

1. When I search for `foo` I will get only `foo` as result.
2. When I search for `foo*` I will be getting `foo` **and** `foobar` as result.

What I want is:

When I search for `foo` I will get `foo` **and** `foobar`, regardless of language.

Is there any way to elegantly solve this. I'm prepared to solve this with a custom module for example.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the [Porter Stemmer](http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module to handle that, it works a treat.

> This module implements the Porter stemming algorithm to improve English-language searching with the Drupal built-in Search module.
>
> The process of stemming reduces each word in the search index to its basic root or stem (e.g. 'blogging' to 'blog') so that variations on a word ('blogs', 'blogger', 'blogging', 'blog') are considered equivalent when searching. This generally results in more relevant search results.

Comment: Hm... that would work if my customer's website would be in English, but it's international: English, Dutch, Spanish, German and French.

Comment: Ah ok. Might be worth looking at how that module does it's indexing, it would give you a good place to start. Bear in mind you're going to be forced to run `LIKE xyz%` against the database which can get quite inefficient, but without a stemming algorithm you don't have much other choice